# I am trying to SimpleDateFormat date in java

Tags: java, time, simpledateformat

I am trying to format a date by parsing it and then formating it but it is not working.

It is showing a parsing exception

```
public java.util.Date convertFormat(String DateTimeForm) 
                    throws ParseException {
 DateTimeForm="2012-06-01 10:00 PM";
 DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm aaa");
 java.util.Date FCDate = (java.util.Date) formatter.parse(DateTimeForm);

 return (java.util.Date) FCDate;

}
```

Comment: maybe showing the error log would help

Comment: And provide your locale.

Comment: Other than making no sense as a method (because you completely ignore the value passed in), there's nothing wrong with the code you've shown.  It compiles and behaves the way (I think) you would intend.  Can you post your locale?

Comment: Try this: new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm aaa",java.util.Locale.US);

Comment: The OP's operating system might be a different language than English.

Comment: What is the idea in setting formatter to null, first?

Answer (score 1):

This works fine on my machine.  I didn't change anything important.

```
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm aaa"); 
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = formatter.parse("2012-06-01 10:00 PM");
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        // Intentionally empty. Failed parse causes date == null. 
    }
    System.out.print(date);
```

prints

```
    Fri Jun 01 22:00:00 EDT 2012
```

The Java docs say the numerics are all locale-independent, but not the AM/PM.  For example the code fails if you specify `Locale.JAPAN` in the formatter construction.  Specify `Local.US` to guarantee AM/PM will always work.

Comment: I added a comment to show why in this case it's a reasonable thing to do.

Comment: Yes, and then you print it out.

Answer (score 1):

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm aaa");
try {
    Date date = formatter.parse("2012-06-01 10:00 PM");
    System.out.println(date.toString());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Didn't change anything and yet it works.

```
Fri Jun 01 22:00:00 CDT 2012
```

Comment: Thank it is working but i dont know why when i throw exception it is not working but when i try catch it is working. what is the reason

Comment: @VICKY-TSC looking in the Java [`DateFormat#parse`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String)) method documentation, it says that throws a ParseException, and `SimpleDateFormat#parse` is a subclass of `DateFormat`, inheriting the `parse` method.